# perl to python...how do I?

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to learn python but don't quite understand the syntax. What is the equivalent of:

```
my $string='this one this that this here ';
while($string=~/this\s+(.*?)\s+/g){
    print $1."\n";
 }
```

prints:

```
one
that
here
```

Comment: @MK. Please explain the funnies.

Comment: I find the combination of Perl and "I don't understand the Python syntax" amusing.  Hope I didn't hurt anybody's feelings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `re` module. I think this is equivalent, modulo some of the side-effects on `string`:

```
import re
string = "this one this that this here "
for match in re.finditer(r"this\s+(.*?)\s+", string):
    print match.group(1)
```